# Three.js + webxr animations not playing from .glb file

Tags: animation, three.js, gltf, webxr

I am unable to get the animation clips from the .glb file to play. The .glb model loads and is displayed on the screen but the animation does not play.

The animations play fine when viewing the object in the three.js editor.

The .glb has 1 animation clip associated with it.

Any Help would be much appreciated!!!

```
import {
  Mesh,
  AmbientLight,
  Clock,
  AnimationMixer,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  Scene,
  WebGLRenderer,
  MeshBasicMaterial,
  RingGeometry,
  sRGBEncoding
} from 'three';
import {ARButton} from 'three/examples/jsm/webxr/ARButton';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'

class App {
  constructor() {
    this.clock = new Clock();
    this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    this.camera.position.set(0, 1.6, 3);
    this.scene = new Scene();

    this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true
    });
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.renderer.outputEncoding = sRGBEncoding;
    document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    this.initXR();
    this.initScene();

    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize.bind(this), false);
    this.renderer.setAnimationLoop(this.render.bind(this));
  }

  initXR() {
    this.renderer.xr.enabled = true;
    document.body.appendChild(ARButton.createButton(this.renderer, {requiredFeatures: ['hit-test']}));

    this.hitTestSourceRequested = false;
    this.hitTestSource = null;

    this.controller = this.renderer.xr.getController(0);
    this.controller.addEventListener('select', this.onSelect.bind(this));
  }

  initScene() {
    let geometry = new RingGeometry(0.08, 0.10, 32).rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
    let material = new MeshBasicMaterial();
    this.reticle = new Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.reticle.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    this.reticle.visible = false;
    this.scene.add(this.reticle);

    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('./models/stylized_character.glb', gltf => {
      this.myObj = gltf;
      gltf.scene.scale.set(.25, .25, .25);
      gltf.scene.visible = true;
      this.scene.add(gltf.scene);

      //todo: this doesnt seem to work
      this.mixer = new AnimationMixer(gltf);
      var action = this.mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]);
      action.play();
    });

    var aLight = new AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
    this.scene.add(aLight)
  }

  render(_, frame) {
    const delta = this.clock.getDelta();
    if (this.mixer) {
      this.mixer.update(delta);
    } 
    if (frame) {
      if (this.hitTestSourceRequested === false) {
        this.requestHitTestSource();
      }
      if (this.hitTestSource) {
        this.getHitTestResults(frame);
      }
    }
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  onWindowResize() {
    this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  onSelect() {
    if (this.reticle.visible) {

      this.myObj.scene.position.setFromMatrixPosition(this.reticle.matrix);
      this.myObj.scene.visible = true;

    }
  }

  async requestHitTestSource() {
    const session = this.renderer.xr.getSession();
    session.addEventListener('end', () => {
      this.hitTestSourceRequested = false;
      this.hitTestSource = null;
    });
    const referenceSpace = await session.requestReferenceSpace('viewer');
    this.hitTestSource = await session.requestHitTestSource({space: referenceSpace, entityTypes: ['plane']});
    this.hitTestSourceRequested = true;
  }

  getHitTestResults(frame) {
    const hitTestResults = frame.getHitTestResults(this.hitTestSource);
    if (hitTestResults.length) {
      const hit = hitTestResults[0];
      const pose = hit.getPose(this.renderer.xr.getReferenceSpace());
      this.reticle.visible = true;
      this.reticle.matrix.fromArray(pose.transform.matrix);
    } else {
      this.reticle.visible = false;
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  new App();
});
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the JS Console, if any? The line `new AnimationMixer(gltf);` needs to pass `gltf.scene` into the mixer, not the container object.

Comment: You were right that fixed the issue!!!